# Writing a program that creates a directory and creates a file in that directory using c language

Tags: c

I have been trying the following code in a certain certain program but it just creates the directory without putting in it.

What it only does is creating the file out of the directory, that is, as a neighbor to the folder.

```
mkdir(dir2, 0666);

DIR *dr1 = opendir(dir2);

fl = open("copy.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644);

write(fl, buff, 512);

close (fl);
closedir(dr1);
```

Comment: [Open letter to students](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/6166)

Comment: The [`opendir`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html) function doesn't do what you apparently think it does. You want the [`chdir`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html) function.

Comment: dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22949500/create-file-inside-a-directory-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append the path of the folder to the name of the file :

```
fl = open(strcat(directory_path, "/copy.txt"), O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644);
```

where `directory_path` is a character string, which stores the location of the folder created.

```
char directory_path[100];
strcpy(directory_path, dir2);
```

`strcat` is the function used for concatenating two strings, defined in `string.h`.

Comment: thanks very much it helped

Answer (score 1):

You want this:

```
mkdir(dir2, 0666);        // create directory
                          // construct the filename "directory/copy.txt"
char filename[200];
strcpy(filename, dir2);
strcat(filename, "/");
strcat(filename "copy.txt");    

fl = open(filename, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644);

write(fl, buff, 512);

close (fl);
```

You don't need `opendir` ann `closedir` here.

Discalaimer: this is non error checking and untested code only for demonstrations purposes.